# Grunt + protractor + cucumber issue

Tags: selenium, webdriver, cucumber, gruntjs, protractor

OS: Windows 7

I am currently trying to setup an automated testing process for an angularjs app with grunt.

This was going well until I hit a snag which although will not stop progress is really annoying and I'd like to resolve it.

The grunt dependencies I have:

```
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.8.0",
"protractor": "^0.24.1",
"grunt-protractor-webdriver": "^0.1.8",
"grunt-protractor-runner": "^1.0.0",
"cucumber": "^0.4.0",
"chai": "^1.9.1",
"chai-as-promised": "^4.1.1",
```

I initially started with a simple protractor config file using jasmine and a related spec file using the following stack:

```
connect
protractor_webdriver
protractor
```

This worked fine, the webserver started on the requested port, Selenium Server started then Chrome was launched, the test passed, Chrome was closed and the grunt process finished. I could immediately re-run the command with no issue if necessary

I moved on to create another protractor config file but this time using cucumber instead. The relate feature and steps files were created and I changed the 'protractor' task to point to this instead. Everything ran OK as before and the test passed, however the Chrome browser is closed and although Grunt seemed to exit and a new command prompt was shown I couldn't use the up arrow to access previous commands and if I typed a new one this just hangs and doesn't do anything. The only way around this was to CTRL + C twice which returns another command prompt and then it behaves as expected.

Edit: If I take out the 'protractor_webdriver' task and have the Selenium Server running separately then I do not get the command prompt issue, however the Chrome is still not shut down (I do not want this as a solution though as I want everything to be self-contained).

Has anyone experienced this before or have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. There is an issue with both of these that ChromeDriver is left running as a process but believe this to be unrelated (although resolving this would be preferable as well).

Answer (score 0):

I believe if the test has failed, Chrome browser hangs and won't close. 
I have managed to get Angular, Cucumber, Protractor working together using Grunt. It is pretty much like what you had:

connect
protractor_webdriver
protractor

I have a working sample
https://github.com/frozenamazon/open-weather

Comment: this doesn't make a nice answer